# StackExchange's tag "synonyms" aren't. What should they be called?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

StackExchange sites use [tags](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags) to help users sort, search, group and filter the large volume of questions and answers.

Sometimes there are cases where a tag has a common misspelling, or a meaning similar to another more common tag, or describes a (non-useful) subset of the things described by another tag.  Because SE wants tags to be as useful as possible, and used as uniformly as possible, it provides a mechanism to automatically turn the less useful of a pair of tags into the more useful of that pair.  StackExchange calls these tag pairs *tag synonyms* and provides a user interface where high-rep users can [propose new synonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms/synonyms) for a tag.  Here's an example of the current user interface (from the [Computer Science StackExchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com)).

> [image: StackExchange synonym suggestion UI]

Personally, I can't tell whether it has been proposed that *notation* be used instead of *terminology* or that *terminology* be used instead of *notation*.  And apparently no-one else can figure it out either, because this user interface is used wrong-way-around about as often as it is used as intended.  Part of the problem is with the use of the term *synonym*.  A *synonym* is

> a word or phrase that means exactly or nearly the same as another word or phrase in the same language [Google].

That is, synonymity is an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).  In particular synonymity is [symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation).  Given a pair of tags [a](/questions/tagged/a) and [b](/questions/tagged/b), "[a](/questions/tagged/a) is a synonym for [b](/questions/tagged/b)" implies  "[b](/questions/tagged/b) is a synonym for [a](/questions/tagged/a)."  But that's not how StackExchange tag "synonyms" work.  The system is supposed to either automatically convert [b](/questions/tagged/b) into [a](/questions/tagged/a) (always) or automatically convert [b](/questions/tagged/b) into [a](/questions/tagged/a) (always).  That is, it's a [hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy).

What term(s) should StackExchange be using here?

(Just for the record there is apparently another place, in the StackExchange moderator tools, where they use non-symmetric terminology, but it is still not clear which way the replacement is intended.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142891/fixing-the-sucktastic-merge-ui-for-tags.)

Comment: *I can't tell whether it has been proposed that.... And apparently no-one else can figure it out either, because this user interface is used wrong-way-around about as often as it is used as intended.* And *it is still not clear which way the replacement is intended.* Your question belongs on Meta, since it is about the site UI. It is not primarily about English language & usage.

Comment: Eventually a meta post should probably happen.  But it would be pointless to make a request on meta if no-one can come up with better terminology than the UI currently has.  Hence my question to the experts on English language and usage, I can't think of anyone better to ask for a suggestion.

Comment: I suggest that "alias" might be a useful word in this context. Alias would imply that it is not the original - it is "another name by which something is known". In computers, an alias is a link to a file, not the file itself.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - per se, not say

Comment: Wandering, perhaps you should reword the question to focus more on the word you wish to change.